# How to retrieve data from useEffect with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a service that returns user data:

```
export const AccountRequest = async () => {
    const token = await retrieveToken();
    try {
        if (token) {
            const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.65:8000/api/user/me/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            console.log(response);
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        error("can't retrieve data");
    }
};
```

And I have a sreen component where I want to display user name and email:

```
export const SetScreen = ({ navigation }) => {  
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
    

    useEffect(() => {
        AccountRequest().then((data) => {
            console.log(data.email);
        });
    }, [query]);

    return (
        <AccountBackground>
            <AccountCover />
            <Title>Instellingen</Title>
            <AccountContainer>
                <Spacer position="top" size="large">
                    <Text variant="label">{query.email}</Text>              
                </Spacer>               
            </AccountContainer>         
        </AccountBackground>
    );
};
```

and from the useEffect I get the correct data returned: user@user.nl.

But how to return this data propertie in the Text component?

```
<Text>{query.email}</Text>
```

Question: how to return the email adsress in the Text component?

Comment: Store it in state? That's an exceedingly common pattern covered in any basic tutorial.

Comment: Yes, so it's not at all clear what's stopping you using it _for this_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create one user state and once the data is retrieved saved it in that state.

Try this

```
export const SetScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    AccountRequest().then(data => {
      console.log(data.email);
      setUserData(data);
    });
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <AccountBackground>
      <AccountCover />
      <Title>Instellingen</Title>
      <AccountContainer>
        <Spacer position="top" size="large">
          <Text variant="label">{userData?.email}</Text>
          <Text>{userData?.email}</Text>
        </Spacer>
      </AccountContainer>
    </AccountBackground>
  );
};
```

I hope this will help you out!